# Vim search and replace non-greedy

Tags: regex, vim, non-greedy

I want to match all content non-greedily between words ABC and XYZ

```
ABC ....
...
... XYZ


ABC ...
...
...
...
XYZ
```

where ... represents any characters. The number of words and lines between ABC and XYZ may be 1 or more.

I tried using

```
:%s/ABC\(.*\)\n\(.*\n\)*\(.*\)XYZ//gc
```

The \(.*\n)* is making vim complain about memory usage.

How do i do this inside vim without looking to perl?

Comment: You are looking for ``:%s/ABC\(\_.\{-}\)XYZ//gc`. See `:h /\_.`, `:h /\{-`, and `:h  perl-patterns`.

Comment: I like this version: `%s/ABC\zs\_.\{-}\zeXYZ//gc`